# How to insert special characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I need to insert values in description column that have special characters. Can anyone guide.

```
INSERT INTO accident_report ( Occurrence_Date, accident_category, Occurrence_Time, Machine_Location, affected, Machine_category, Machine_Number, description)
VALUE 
('2021-05-03', 'Minor', '14:19', 'shed 2', 'machine', 'CNC', '23', 'test');
```

Comment: Please add the SQL for the table (so we know what the data types are) and specify what the "special" data is you want to insert - I'm assuming you have unicode characters which are outside the "normal" ASCII character set.

Comment: @tony, Being a text field where description / details are to be typed special characters includes most of them which are provided on the keyboard - @#$%^&*()_+[{}]|\:;'"<>,.?/

Comment: Some special chars must be quoted. For shown chars - slash char and single quote char must be doubled. I.e. ```.. VALUES ( .. ,   '@#$%^&*()_+[{}]|\\:;''"<>,.?/'   , .. )```

Comment: Those characters are hardly special. What exact problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all the characters you list can be directly inserted in to a `text` or `char` field without problems.

Depending on the quote character you use you only need to "escape" the same character, so when using single quotes `'` you don't have to escape double quotes `"`. With the quote you can either escape it with a back slash `\` or double up the character `''`.

Back slash characters also need to be escaped or doubled up.

Here's an example of how to handle the different characters: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qiV1AsQdRYLZkUE4HAzWgu/1

```sql
create table accident_report (id integer, description text);

insert accident_report(id, description) values 
(1, '@#$%^&*()_+[{}]|:;"<>,.?/'),
(2, '\\'),
(3, '\''),
(4, '''');

select * from accident_report;
```

Interestingly the markdown code colouring doesn't quite get it right with the double quoted characters.